# Generate a report on logging level

Tags: java

i am trying to generate a report based on the number of logger.error we have in our production code as some of these need to be reduced to warn to help production support monitoring.

Is there any easy way to generate a report on this other than searching in eclipse for logger.error all all .java files?

I am thinking maybe a shell script to search the .java files and maybe output a file based on this?

Thanks

Comment: What info do you need exactly? In what point isn't eclispse's search tool enough? By the way, instead of performing a file search on java files, I would perform a Java search which will allow you to find each call of `error` method whatever the name of the Logger variable.

Answer (score 1):

What about using this i a unix shell:

```
 find  -name *.java | xargs cat | grep "logger.error" | wc -l
```

In detail:

List all `.java` files:
`find  -name *.java`

List content of all `.java` files: 
`find  -name *.java | xargs cat`

Filter to get only the lines with *logger.error* :
`find  -name *.java | xargs cat | grep "logger.error"`

Cout the output:
`find  -name *.java | xargs cat | grep "logger.error" | wc -l`

I am quite sure there is an easier way, but that is the first approach that came in my mind, and seams to work on my project.

Comment: +1 for command line use! Note that this won't catch when the logger is not called logger...

Comment: @Behe: You are right, but handling this would need need quite some complex logic. And the question looks like you can assume that it is appropriate to search for `logger.error`. Another problem may be if the is e.g. a linebreak between `logger` and `.error`.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment, I would perform a Java search on `error` method which will allow you to find each call of error method whatever the name of the Logger variable.

It can be necessary to also look for `log`method

It will prevent all the issues you could encounter (different variable names, splitted line...)